# Incorrect starting page number on inserted PDF

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, pdfpages, double-sided

I'm having issues the TOC not displaying the section page number correctly for a PDF included in my appendix. Essentially setting the page number argument to "1" in the `addtotoc`option makes the TOC list the starting page number of the inserted PDF as one page before the first page. A sample of the code looks like this:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside, open=right, fontsize=13pt, DIV=calc, chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,hcentering,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\appendix
\chapter{Articles}

\includepdf[pages=-, openright=true, addtotoc={1, section, 1, {Article 1}, article1}, pagecommand={}, trim=25mm 0mm 25mm 0mm, offset=3mm 0, width=\textwidth]{chapters/Article1/article1.pdf}
```

While the first page in the PDF starts on page 85, the TOC displays page 84 as the first page:

[image]

I therefore tried setting first page to 2 (`addtotoc={2, section, 1, {Article 1}, article1}`, but then TOC displays *page 86*:

[image]

Removing `openright=true` seem to set the page number correctly, but then the PDF starts on an even page, which I do not want.

Furthermore, adding labels doesn't show up when citing references.

Any suggestions?

Comment: looks like a bug of pdfpages. But you can add `\cleardoublepage` before the \includepdf to get around it.

Comment: Perhaps it is not a bug. openright seems to add an empty page unconditionally, so it is not really suited to get the first page on the right. `\cleardoublepage` is better.

Comment: Your workaround worked almost like a charm. TOC now displays the pages correctly. However, the even page before the inserted PDF is now completely blank, meaning the header and footer is now also gone. Is there a way to avoid this?    Btw, you may be right it's not a bug: `openright=true` seems to [intentionally leave a blank page before the first logical page](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf). I realized after posting that one of my included PDFs starts on an even page after leaving an odd page blank. The incorrect page numbering in TOC clearly is a bug, though.

Comment: the KOMA classes have an number of `\clearXXX-variants` to get every page style you want on the empty page. Check the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I will. `\cleardoublepage` worked though, so if post it as an answer, I'll tick it off as a solution.